# Utf8 encoding issue ! UTF8Characters in Invoke function of NPAPI?

Tags: c++, firefox, plugins, npapi

Deal with utf8 encoding issues is really a pain when I make firefox plug-in with NPAPI. Especially when it comes to Invoke function ( Invoke(NPIdentifier name, const NPVariant *args, uint32_t argCount, NPVariant *result) ). When it gets a call from js, I can get the parameters posted by using the code bellow:  std::string strParam = args[0].value.stringValue.UTF8Characters; Here comes the problem! When I sent strParam back to browser or wrote it to a utf8 encoding txt, it turned out all messy codes. Is UTF8Characters not Utf8 encoded string?! If not, is there a way to get a utf8 string from it?

Any helps? I am hungerd for your rescue!

ps: project character-set: Unicode.

Comment: This seems like an odd question to be asking on the same day that Firefox dropped support for NPAPI plugins...

Comment: what's new for firefox plugins development? PPAPI?

Comment: PPAPI was only ever supported by Chrome/Chromium. In general binary extensions are a dying breed; Firefox only supports [WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) as of now.

Comment: Thanks 4 ur advices.However, I am not sure whether js functions in a webextension are able to communicate with some devices connected to PC via dll or serial port for some security considerations. Am I allowed to call js function to open a camera or some hardwares else ?

Comment: I believe you can access (most?) webcams and such via WebRTC, a new standard. But as far as I'm aware modern web browsers don't want websites communicating directly with the operating system -- let alone hardware such as serial ports -- due to the risk of creating a security bug. These days you may be better off distributing a binary application that has its own HTTP connectivity than trying to rely on a browser.

Comment: The requirement is to communicate with a windows service using socket in the plugin( or browser like Activex works in IE). If consider extension as a choice, i.e. can js do the socket client job communicating with socket server in the windows service? What about websocket? Does it make any sence?

Comment: You can do that using a WebExtension together with a Native Messaging host.  FireBreath 2 supports this.